# How to set a variable in a .then() to be used in a later .then() - Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, promise

I'm building an online platform for jugglers using ReactJS, Typescript and Firebase. I'm trying to make a system where admins can give out "golden tickets". Users can then send these golden tickets to their friends so that their friends can also make accounts.

I've gotten all the way through to the actual creation of the account.

The problem is, I need to do four things when they click `Create Account` (and currently, I do them in this order):

1. Upload their Profile Picture to `firebase.storage`
2. Create the user with their email and password using `firebase.auth`
3. Update the user's displayName and photoURL in `firebase.auth`
4. Create a doc for the user in `firebase.firestore` using the information that we have collected in the other steps.

At the moment it isn't working because in the later steps, some variables come up undefined.

Here is the code:

```
doRegisterWithEmailPasswordAndPhoto = async (
        email: string,
        password: string,
        firstname: string,
        lastname: string,
        username: string,
        photo: File | null
    ) => {
        let tempuid: string | null = null;
        let tempPhotoURL: string | null = null;
        await this.storage
            .ref()
            .child('profile-pictures/' + username)
            .put(photo ? photo : exampleProfilePic)
            .then((photoRef: firebase.storage.UploadTask) => {
                    tempPhotoURL = photoRef.snapshot.downloadURL;
                    return this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email,
                        password
                    );
            })
            .then((res: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => {
                if (res.user) {
                    tempuid = res.user.uid;
                    return res.user.updateProfile({
                        displayName: firstname + ' ' + lastname,
                        photoURL: tempPhotoURL,
                    });
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.db.collection('users').doc(tempuid).set({
                    firstname: firstname,
                    lastname: lastname,
                    username: username,
                    email: email,
                    admin: false,
                    forumPosts: 0,
                    created: this.dbFunc.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                });
            });
    };
```

So, as you can see, I tried to solve it by creating two temporary variables to store the items: `tempuid` and `tempPhotoURL`. But I am still getting `uid is undefined` errors.

Hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't mix await and `then()` for cases like this. All your promises should just be awaited and you can get rid of all the `then` functions.

Comment: if `res.user` is false you will not get an id.